# Weirdness with ABAddressBook and CFRelease

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, abaddressbook

I have a strange thing happening with ABAddressBook. Here is some code:

```
- (NSArray*)addressBookArray {

    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = NULL;
    NSArray *temp = nil;

    if(&ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions != NULL) {

        CFErrorRef error = nil;
        addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if(error) {
                    // handle error
                }
                else if(!granted) {
                    // handle not granted
                }
            });
        });
    }
    else { // iOS 5
        addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    }
    if(addressBook) {
        temp = (__bridge_transfer NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
        CFRelease(addressBook);
    }
    return temp;
}

- (NSArray*)emailList {

    NSArray *temp = [self addressBookArray];
    NSMutableArray *list = nil;

    if(temp) {

        int n = temp.count;
        list = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:n];

        for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++) {

            ABRecordRef person = (__bridge ABRecordRef)[temp objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *name = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person);

            if(name) {
                ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);

                if(emails) {
                    int cnt = ABMultiValueGetCount(emails);

                    for(int j = 0; j < cnt; j++) {
                        NSString *email = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, j);

                        if(email) {
                            [list addObject:email];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    CFRelease(emails);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

If I call `emailList` and comment out `CFRelease(addressBook)`, I get a warning of a possible leak in XCode's Analyze, but my code behaves properly.

If I uncomment `CFRelease(addressBook)`, there is no leak warning, `ABRecordRef person` and `NSString *name` have proper values, BUT `ABMultiValueRef emails` if always nil.

Confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it surprises me somewhat, I suspect that the `ABPerson` is not completely defined without its `ABAddressBook`. So the address book needs to exist for as long as the person. Given that, as long as this is all single-threaded, you may want to store your `ABAddressBook` in an ivar so you don't have to create and destroy it all the time. If it's multi-threaded, remember that you need a separate `ABAddressBook` per thread.

Comment: Based on my own experience with these APIs, I believe Rob is correct.

Comment: An ivar it is. Kinda strange that releasing the original addressbook hobbles the copy.